# AMP page linked from non amp page not displaying on mobile

Tags: amp-html

I have the following page https://checkmywork.info/ which links to the amp page https://checkmywork.info/wp-content/themes/marqeta/amp.html . The amp page is successfully validated and doesn't throw any errors but when I try to load the page on mobile it still displays the non amp version instead of the amp version of the page. Google search console also says the amp page is valid. Is it because Google still trying to index the site? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? the amp page already has errors no image found
If you are using WordPress I will recommend checking AMP plugin with Reader Mode.

Comment: @MilindMore I guess console errors doesn't have any impact in terms of amp validation but I got rid of the error. My goal is to see the amp version of the page when I go to  https://checkmywork.info/ on my mobile. Currently I am still not seeing it?  I am using Wordpress but the homepage will be an individual page and not wordpress page so I can't use the plugin.

Comment: Use javascript redirect mobile detection script logic and redirect to amphtml URL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: Isn't the redirection to amp page supposed to happen automatically without using javascript? My understanding is that if there is an existing amp page, browsers will try to load that when you are on mobile instead of the regular version of the page

Comment: I am asking you to add a script on non-amp page, which checks if the user browser agent is a mobile device then redirects him to AMP page. so nothing will be on the AMP page

Comment: Thank you. If i add a redirect will that still be considered as AMP validated?